# iOS 8 page indicator styling

Tags: ios, ios8, styling

I am looking for the styling parameters of the page indicators dots in iOS 8, as I am emulating those in my app. Is the following styling information available?

- Diameter (in px) of the page indicators
- Spacing (in px) between the page indicators
- Tint (colour and alpha) of the current page indicator
- Tint (colour and alpha) of the non-current page indicators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The **diameter** of each dot is `7px non-retina` & `14px retina`.
- The **spacing** between each dot is `9px non-retina` & `18px retina`.
- You can set & read the tint color of the **current page** dot by using
  the accessors of the `currentPageIndicatorTintColor` property.
- You can set & read the tint color of the **non-current page** dots by using the accessors of the `pageIndicatorTintColor` property.

To give an example of my answer (size & spacing), here is a sample made by me with custom dots grouped together to resemble an UIPageControl indicator on top of an "original" UIPageControl in Interface Builder:

[image]

Comment: You don't have to use `UIImageView` for the dots. It might be better to use a plain `UIView` but set the `cornerRadius` property on its layer to make it circular. Then you can change the colour and size of the dots more easily.

Comment: As I said in my answer, I used image views only to make a point (as a sample to show the size & spacing). I could have skipped explaining the way I did it altogether since it is irrelevant to the question and the answer itself.

Comment: @Razvan: Thanks! For some reason `NSLog(@"Alpha: %f", CGColorGetAlpha(([[UIPageControl alloc] init]).pageIndicatorTintColor.CGColor));` prints `0.000000`.

Comment: You're welcome! The reason your alpha is 0.000 is because you haven't initialized the `UIPageControl` with any color and alpha.You can either create an `UIPageControl` in `Interface Builder` and set an `IBOutlet` to it and read the default values from it or set the `pageIndicatorTintColor` to some `UIColor` like this: `UIPageControl *pg = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
    [pg setPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:15.0/255.0 green:20.0/255.0 blue:32.0/255 alpha:0.9]];`

Comment: @Randomblue I would say that I correctly answered your question(s) with credible and official materials and examples. Would you please be kind to approve my answer and award the bounty?

Comment: I'm still struggling with getting the *default alpha* used in iOS 8 for `pageIndicatorTintColor`. If I initialise the `UIPageControl` with a colour of my choice, that would overwrite the default, so I would not be able to read it off.

Comment: I've told you to create an `IBOutlet` to a `UIPageControl` in `Interface Builder` if you want the defaults... Create an UIViewController Class`, create an `UIViewController` in `Interface Builder`, make the `UIViewController` in `IB` part of that class, drag an `UIPageControl` somewhere on the `UIViewController` and hook it up to an `IBOutlet` property.  The `Default Color` for an `UIPageControl` is `White` so might want to change the `background color` of your `View` to something dark.

Answer (score 1):

With the properties `@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *pageIndicatorTintColor` and `@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *currentPageIndicatorTintColor` I think it would be possible to get the color of the indicator dots.